# Change the image on UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I a complete beginner when it comes to iOS development. I have recently downloaded a template application so I could learn the basics. I am trying to figure out how to change the photo/image on the bottom UI bar. I have done so much research to no avail.

Comment: That "bottom UI bar" is a UITabBar or a UIToolBar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share background view between tabs on a UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645666/share-background-view-between-tabs-on-a-uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645666/share-background-view-between-tabs-on-a-uitabbarcontroller) you can find an answer, a category in UITabBar that allows you to set a background image programmatically.

Comment: The information in that link is badly out of date, assuming @three3 is using iOS 5

Comment: Comment by @cirrostratus on my answer link: "I have just tested on iOS 5 - and it still works"

Comment: Sure it works, but iOS 5 provides a much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5, UITabBar (and many other UIKit controls) follow a standard procedure for customizing their appearance. Here is a good tutorial on how it works:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5